# Using ioctl with C#

Tags: c#, c, linux, dllimport, libc

I'm trying to use an orangePi spi via C#. There's a code sample in C below. I can import open/ioctl methods using the C# DllImport attribute. But I don't know how to get SPI_IOC_WR_MODE / SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD / SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ values. SPI_IOC_WR_MODE is defined as _IOR(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 1, __u8). So it's not a constant value.

### How can I get an actual SPI_IOC_WR_MODE value from C# ?

```
int wiringPiSPISetupMode (int channel, int speed, int mode)
{
  int fd ;

  mode    &= 3 ;    // Mode is 0, 1, 2 or 3
  channel &= 1 ;    // Channel is 0 or 1

  if ((fd = open (channel == 0 ? spiDev0 : spiDev1, O_RDWR)) < 0)
    return wiringPiFailure (WPI_ALMOST, "Unable to open SPI device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;

  spiSpeeds [channel] = speed ;
  spiFds    [channel] = fd ;

// Set SPI parameters.

  if (ioctl (fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode)            < 0)
    return wiringPiFailure (WPI_ALMOST, "SPI Mode Change failure: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;

  if (ioctl (fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &spiBPW) < 0)
    return wiringPiFailure (WPI_ALMOST, "SPI BPW Change failure: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;

  if (ioctl (fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed)   < 0)
    return wiringPiFailure (WPI_ALMOST, "SPI Speed Change failure: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;

  return fd ;
}
```

Comment: `So it's not a constant value` - well it is, though not a simple one. `_IOC` is a macro - see its definition in ioctl.h.

Comment: Does it mean that I can count that value and it will be always the same ? Is there any table with these values ?